# how to get parameters from url in javascript?

Tags: javascript, query-string

I am trying to get query parameters from the URL in javascript. I tried `window.location.search` and got the params but it happens only the first time I access the URL. Afterwards it is returning empty.

I read somewhere that it is due to **Asynchronous GET** request. So how to get parameters always from the URL in javascript?

Comment: Your assumption is incorrect.  `location.search` will always work, unless the location changes.

Comment: So why is it returning mixed results? Sometimes i am getting the params and sometimes i don't?

Comment: have you tries window.location.hash - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

This might can help for you.

```
var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
    var sPageURL = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1)),
        sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
        sParameterName,
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
        sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

        if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
            return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
};
And this is how you can use this function assuming the URL is,
http://dummy.com/?technology=jquery&blog=jquerybyexample.

var tech = getUrlParameter('technology');
var blog = getUrlParameter('blog');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function Myfunction(myvar){
  var urls = myvar;
  var myurls = urls.split("?id="); //will return the parameter after "?"
  var mylasturls = myurls[1];
  var mynexturls = mylasturls.split("&");
  var url = mynexturls[0];
  alert(url)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new javascript APIs, **[URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL)** and **[URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)**

```js
var link = new URL('https://google.com.ec?q=blable%20bli&q=2312&dog=true')
var params = link.searchParams
var keys = [...new Set([...params.keys()])]

console.log('keys: ', keys)

for (var key of keys)
    console.log(key, params.getAll(key))
```