# How do I get parameters from URL in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, url, parameters

Hi could somebody please tell me how I can get parameters from URL in javascript and display the parameters in HTML. I've read this [how to get parameters from url in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46324730/how-to-get-parameters-from-url-in-javascript) . But I do not understand it. Could you please help me?

> something like React error decoder that shows the error according to URL provided.

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/901144/1138712

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)